# Responsive code blocks

Tags: css, pre

I have seen many websites with code blocks on my cellphone, but only a few were responsive. If the code lines were to long I couldn't see the rest of the code. I am also now developing a website with code in. How can I make the code blocks responsive? Here is my code.

```
pre {
    width: 70%;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
    color: #ededed;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you couldn't get the line numbers work with `word-wrap:break-word`, simply use Alex Gorbatchev's syntax highlighter like everyone else ;) No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: On my opinion it is not always a good idea to re-use other parts.
This answer does not... answer to the question directly.

Comment: The script I recommended is flexible and scalable (you can select which syntaxes and styles you need). My answer is not a copypaste, that's true. But it actually helps people who weren't aware that there's a better solution.

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to give the pre block an overflow property to hide the excess or cause it to scroll. The other solution is to have it wrap.

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap; //css3
    white-space: moz-pre-wrap; //firefox
    white-space: -pre-wrap; //opera 4-6
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; //opera 7
    word-wrap: break-word; //internet explorer
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In 2018, the solution that worked for me is to use the `white-space:` property with a value of "**pre-wrap**" like below:

```
.markdown-body pre>code {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

The value "**pre-line**" may work too if you are ok with the collapsing of multiple whitespaces.

The value "**pre**" doesn't work for me as it only breaks if there's a new line in the source (useless when there are very long litteral urls in source).

Here is how [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) describes the relevant values of the `white-space:` property:

**pre** :
    Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at `<br>` elements.

**pre-wrap** :
    Sequences of whitespace are preserved. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

**pre-line** :
    Sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Answer (score 2):

the word-wrap CSS property has been mapped to word-break. Therefore, using the CSS attribute word-break: break-word; can also help resolve the issue

```css
code {
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>
      The HTML <code>button</code> tag defines a clickable button.
    </p>
    <p>The CSS property defines the background color of an element.</p>
    <div>
      <code>
        gclid={gclid}&utm_id={campaignid}
        &utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign={campaignid}&utm_term=
        {adgroupid}&utm_content={creative}
      </code>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pre {
  padding: 0.1em 0.5em 0.3em 0.7em;
  border-left: 11px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1.7em 0 1.7em 0.3em;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 93%;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace, sans-serif;

}
```